# Home Improvement account missing from associated accounts tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I noticed that my [Home Improvement account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/22?tab=accounts#tab-top) is missing from the associated accounts tab on my user profile on the other SO and SE sites for example on my [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146318?tab=accounts#tab-top) here on meta.  Just to prove that it's not a caching issue, I created an account on the Cooking site and it showed up on the other sites immediately.

(I noticed this with Electronic Gadgets too when it first went into beta, but it didn't register with me at the time and I never went back to see if it changed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Home Improvement is still in private beta. As soon as it will move to public beta, it will appear. At least this is how it worked so far.